# Pandas: Select rows that contain any substring from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, substring

I would like to select those rows in a column that contains any of the substrings in a list. This is what I have for now.

```
product = ['LID', 'TABLEWARE', 'CUP', 'COVER', 'CONTAINER', 'PACKAGING']

df_plastic_prod = df_plastic[df_plastic['Goods Shipped'].str.contains(product)]

df_plastic_prod.info()
```

Sample df_plastic

```
Name          Product
David        PLASTIC BOTTLE
Meghan       PLASTIC COVER
Melanie      PLASTIC CUP 
Aaron        PLASTIC BOWL
Venus        PLASTIC KNIFE
Abigail      PLASTIC CONTAINER
Sophia       PLASTIC LID
```

Desired df_plastic_prod

```
Name          Product
Meghan       PLASTIC COVER
Melanie      PLASTIC CUP 
Abigail      PLASTIC CONTAINER
Sophia       PLASTIC LID
```

Thanks in advance! I appreciate any assistance on this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For match values by subtrings join all values of list by `|` for regex `or` - so get values `LID` or `TABLEWARE` ...:

Solution working well also with 2 or more words in `list`.

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in product)
df_plastic_prod = df_plastic[df_plastic['Product'].str.contains(pat)]
print (df_plastic_prod)
      Name            Product
1   Meghan      PLASTIC COVER
2  Melanie        PLASTIC CUP
5  Abigail  PLASTIC CONTAINER
6   Sophia        PLASTIC LID
```

Comment: Question: Why we need to have `\b` in `pat`?

Comment: @balderman - It is called word boundaries, it is necessary for match by all word/s - avoid match `cat` in words `bobcat is nice`, maching `cat is nice`

Comment: I see. So `pat` is actually a regexp and the term 'word boundaries' is taken from the regexp domain. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is using regex to parse the `'Product'` column, and test if any of the extracted values are in the `product` list, then filter the original DataFrame on the results.

In this case, a very simple regex pattern is used (`(\w+)$`) which matches a single word at the end of a line.

Sample code:

```
df.iloc[df['Product'].str.extract('(\w+)$').isin(product).to_numpy(), :]
```

Output:

```
      Name            Product
1   Meghan      PLASTIC COVER
2  Melanie        PLASTIC CUP
5  Abigail  PLASTIC CONTAINER
6   Sophia        PLASTIC LID
```

Setup:

```
product = ['LID', 'TABLEWARE', 'CUP', 
           'COVER', 'CONTAINER', 'PACKAGING']

data = {'Name': ['David', 'Meghan', 'Melanie', 
                 'Aaron', 'Venus', 'Abigail', 'Sophia'],
        'Product': ['PLASTIC BOTTLE', 'PLASTIC COVER', 'PLASTIC CUP', 
                    'PLASTIC BOWL', 'PLASTIC KNIFE', 'PLASTIC CONTAINER',
                    'PLASTIC LID']}
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```